# Welding and range power cords interchangeable? Please help

Tags: wiring, range

I have not been able to find anyone that has the issue that I do. I’ll quickly summarize I bought a range for powder coating. I assume it was an older 3prong originally . I have a receptacle for a welding three prong that has the two vertical polarized flat plugs in relation to the Small one. Can I wire this plug that I have that’s actually for welding directly to the stove is six gauge wire I think stoves are usually eight but other than that it runs the welding machine fine, so I’m just looking for some guidance here on if I can take cut end in picture and direct wire to stove. I know there’s a white, black and green wire on the  on the cut end. I’m just not sure if that  will work or not in relation to the red white and black connectors on the range.. Any help is so greatly appreciate it.

Adding 2 pics. One is the back of range and the wire I plan to wire to the range. The second is the male end of the cord that goes to the corresponding wall receptacle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Photos are worth so much more :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How much current does the device draw?
How much current is the receptacle rated for?
How much current is the plug rated for?

Comment: So you're using the oven on the range for powder coating duty? Is the oven thermostat mechanical or electronic?

Comment: What are the brands/models of all the equipment involved? Once you know that, it's pretty simple to look up the mfgr's specs to see _exactly_ what breaker, wire and receptacle requirements each thing has. Once you know that, you'll know the answer to your question. Until then, all we can do is guess and a bad guess can lead to _your_ place burning down.

Comment: This is closed so I'll answer here.  With no size reference it is a guess, but your plug looks like a NEMA 6-50P Plug.  My welder needs 48 amps so I have a 50 amp breaker with 6 AWG wire and a NEMA 6-50R receptacle on the wall.  My welder and tempering furnace both take 240 VAC but I only have one 240 circuit.  The solution is to put 6-50P plugs on both devices and plug them in as needed.  Wiring white and black to the two sides of the 240 and the green to the neutral will get you going.  Remember, if you are not sure, consult a qualified electrician, don't get zapped.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

(the 50A sockets are slightly different, the NEMA 6-50 has vertical pins).

The old 3-prong range and dryer outlets are dangerous and obsolete. They don't have ground, and that means if the neutral wire has a problem, it can electrify the chassis of the dryer.

The welder needs hot-hot-GROUND.

What makes the old 3-prong range outlets extra dangerous is that (for some reason) they tie the chassis of the range TO THE NEUTRAL.  But if the neutral wire fails it guarantees the chassis will be electrified at 120V!!!   Their logic was "that will rarely fail, since dryer and range connections are rarely disturbed". Unfortunately there are several fatalities a year proving them wrong.  It's even worse with ranges - at least a dryer will stop working when neutral breaks, but a range will keep working with a broken neutral.

Now, 4-wire range connections disconnect the chassis from neutral and connect it to ground, obviously.

So my best recommendation, since you're not making high cuisine here, is to go ahead and wire the range according to the 4-wire instructions (removing the neutral-ground strap) **and then just don't connect neutral to anything at all**.  Most likely the oven will work just fine, just, the oven light won't light.  No big deal, and beats dying.

Comment: nice one, with pictures

Answer (score 1):

You can't to what you want to do. Your welder needs 120V, 120V and a ground so that's 240V & ground. Your cord has black, white & green wire so one hot goes to black, the other hot goes to white (code lets you do that) and ground goes to green.

Your oven needs 120V, 120V, a neutral and a ground. It's not straight 240V like the welder, It needs 120V also so the neutral is required. The cord you want to use has a black, white and green wire. If the black goes to the black wire, the white to the white (neutral) and the green to ground.... guess what, nothing to the red so oven won't work. Even if you foolishly decided not to ground the oven, you would never be allowed to use the green wire to connect to the red oven wire and change the outlet. You need a four wire cord, plug and outlet or a grounded FMC with a black, red and white wire